Confusion regarding Kant's "Table of Transcendental Concepts of Reason" in Prolegomena
I am currently reading Kant's Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics, Edited by Gary Hatfield, and I came across a passage in the "Appendix to pure natural science" that references a "table of transcendental concepts of reason".
Kant writes:
But the usefulness of this separated table of categories shines forth yet more brightly if, as will soon be done, we separate from the categories the table of transcendental concepts of reason, which have a completely different nature and origin than the concepts of the understanding (so that the table must also have a different form), a separation that, necessary as it is, has never occurred in any system of metaphysics, as a result of which these ideas of reason and concepts of the understanding run confusedly together as if they belonged to one family, like siblings, an intermingling that also could never have been avoided in the absence of a separate system of categories.
From this passage, it seems Kant implies there is a distinct "table of transcendental concepts of reason" that is separate from the "table of categories" (concepts of the understanding) found earlier in the text. However, I have not been able to locate this specific table of transcendental concepts of reason in the Prolegomena. I am aware that Kant discusses the concepts of reason, also known as transcendental ideas, later in the book, but there does not appear to be an actual table presented.
My question is: Where can the "table of transcendental concepts of reason" be found in Kant's work? Does it exist within the Prolegomena, or is it fully developed elsewhere, such as in the Critique of Pure Reason?
Any clarification on where to find this table or understanding its role within Kant's overall philosophical system would be greatly appreciated.

"Table" is a big word when it comes to the table of transcendental concepts of reason, a.k.a. transcendental ideas, because "Kant insists that there are only three transcendental ideas — the thinking subject (or soul), the world as a whole (the universe, or the entirety of time and space), and a being of all beings (that is, God) (A334/B391)", see SEP. There is no need for an actual table with just three of them, and the soul, the world and God are addressed mainly in the antinomies of pure reason.

@Conifold Yeah, that's what I suspected. As I was reading that section in the Prolegomena and in CPR (my edition of the Prolegomena contains a selection from CPR) I followed the argument that Kant was presenting but held off on accepting or rejecting it until I would find the "table" and then judge for myself, which obviously never happened. When I first saw the term introduced it just seemed like it would be presented to us in a completely different manner than it was and felt I was missing something. Thanks though, it seems my search is over.

Reason for Kant is purely symbolic without other necessities while the categories are not...

Hey there was a post on this where somebody made a flowchart describing the info. Check it out and see if it works.
Is my understanding on Kant's section contained in the critique of pure reason "The transcendental Aesthetic" correct?

Yes I actually did see this in my search, however I see the flowchart more as an organization tool for relating terms in Kant's philosophy so they are better elucidated, not as a reference to be used when first learning his philosophy. It certainly has it's place but it's not exactly what I was looking for.
